# Julia spawn 'source' leads to no such file or directory

Tags: julia

Julia's `run` function appears to have difficulty running `source`. The wierd thing is that it does not have an issue if I run the exact same command in the shell.

Is there a way to run the command programmatically from Julia?

```
julia> cmd = "/home/me/tensorflow/bin/activate"
"/home/me/tensorflow/bin/activate"

julia> run(`ls $cmd`)
/home/me/tensorflow/bin/activate

julia> run(`source $cmd`)
ERROR: could not spawn `source /home/me/tensorflow/bin/activate`: no such file or directory (ENOENT)
 in _jl_spawn at process.jl:262
 in anonymous at process.jl:415
 in setup_stdio at ./process.jl:403
 in __spawn#58__ at ./process.jl:414
 in run at ./process.jl:530

shell> source /home/me/tensorflow/bin/activate
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

source is built-in command

try like this:

```
run(`zsh -c "source $cmd"`)

run(`bash -c source $cmd`)
```

windows:

```
run(`cmd /c 'echo xxx'`)
```